# Search Problem in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, search, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to search in a table for items which have all of my desired values in a column i.e.
I have table :

```
ID :    1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 3
VALUE : 5 6 5 3 6 7 2 1 9 0
```

I want to give a StoredProc a list of values for example ("6,7,2") and it returns me all IDs that have all the given values in this case it would only returns 2

If I wanted to search for those which at least have one of the values I know I could use "IN" but to have all the values i found nothing.

Thank you in advance

Afshin Arefi

Comment: What database are you using? They each have different features that may support this, so it is important to know.

Comment: I'm Using MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use [table value parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

These allow you to pass in a table of values to a stored procedure and treat it as any other table (use in sub-queries, joins etc).

In terms of the query - if you do use a table value parameter, you can query it for size (how many rows), use `IN` in conjunction with a `GROUP BY` on the `ID` field and a `HAVING` that counts the number of rows.

Comment: Another approach is to temp tables as input/output for a stored procedure, but table variables if applicable are a cleaner solution.

Comment: Thank You
It Worked :

SELECT CMC_ID
FROM [CommodityClass] ,[CommodityClassDynamicAttributes]
WHERE (CMC_ID = CCA_CMC_ID)
  AND (CCA_DAT_ID IN (@CCA_DAT_ID_LIST))
GROUP BY CMC_ID
HAVING COUNT(CCA_DAT_ID) = @CCA_DAT_ID_COUNT